# Jersey 1.17: Redirect when not isUserInRole (redirect-on-403)

Tags: redirect, filter, authorization, jersey-1.0

We use Jersey 1.17 and check if user is allowed to access a resource by implementing SecurityContext#isUserInRole(role) method.

We have a requirement to redirect a user with a particular role to a specific page in case that user doesn't have permissions to access a certain resource. Basically, we want to do a redirect-on-403.

I tried doing this in a filter, but I am not sure how to get a hold of SecurityContext from there and a proper way to terminate filter chain and redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up catching 403 in the client JavaScript code and redirecting the browser window to the desired URL.